# Django form: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: django

I have a form in Django that looks like this

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=FooWidget(def_arg=self.data))
```

Where I call `self.data`, Python throws the exception `name 'self' is not defined`. How can I access `self` there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have answered, there is no `self` to refer to at that point.  Something like this does work though:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo_field = forms.ModelChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo_field'].initial = self.data
```

You can also access the widget in `__init__` through `self.fields['foo_field'].widget`

Answer (score 5):

you can't

at the time the class is created, there is no object instance. for this kind of dynamic behaviour, you need to override the `__init__` method and create the field (or change some of its parameters) there

Answer (score 2):

You can't; there is no `self` there. You'll need to do additional setup in `__init__()`.